# Filling tableadapter with dataset in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have added a dataset and connected with my table (Add New Item >> DataSet)
Then I am trying to use the following code to fill Tableadapter with my dataset.  But it is showing an error.  Could anybody help me please?

```
Dim dAdt As New SqlDataAdapter()
    dAdt.Fill(dsArticles, "tblArticles")
```

Please also note I have put a parameter on my dataset as well `(where ProductID=@PID)`
Thanks

Comment: What "an error message" are you getting? There's only about 87,642 potential ones you could be....

Comment: what's the error? tell that first.....

Comment: Ok I tell you one from 87,642 "dsArticles is a type and can not be used as an expression"

Comment: problem in dsArticles definition. how you have declared, initaialized it and used it before this statement?

Comment: sorry how to initizlise?  I just added to project using Add New Item and then configured the query

Comment: @AnkushRoy AFIK,  adding dataset from Item menu, will do the all thing behind the scense . so he need not to be inialize or declare

Comment: @Ravi :- He just mentioned it in comments man, I never knew before that how the datset has been initialized.
AFIK the error mentioned occurs when some wrong way has been used for construction..as this link :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b851ya5e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx verifies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dataset using Add New >> Dataset and configure it.
Then in the namespace of the forms, add reference as
Imports DemoApplication.dsArticlesTableAdapters

Demoapplication is the name of your application and dsArticles is the name of added DataSet.

Then in the button, where you want to access the dataset and table, add code:

```
' Access Table Adapter
   Dim ta As New tblArticlesTableAdapter()
   ' Access Dataset
   Dim dt As dsArticles.tblArticlesDataTable = ta.GetData(txtArtNo.Text)
   MsgBox(dt.Rows.Count)
```